# simpler way of casting not-undefined type

Tags: typescript

In typescript, is there a better way of writing this code:

```js
return {something: something!}
```

like this(which does not work of course)

```js
return {something!}
```

thanks!

Comment: Narrow `something` to not be `undefined`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: thanks but in thins case I would like to avoid narrowing...

Comment: That depends on what you mean by 'better'. But I think the answer to your question is a simple no